# writing array values to file C#

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

I am trying to write the values of my array to a text file, but my output isn't cooperating.

my code

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\fakeuser\Desktop\C#\New Text Document.txt"))
        {
            string[] values = { "Test", "People", "Owls", "Bully"};
            foreach (string line in values)
                outputFile.WriteLine(values);
```

this is the output I get

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: outputFile.WriteLine(line);

Comment: `outputFile.WriteLine(line);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're writing the array instead of the line you're iterating over. Try this instead:

```
outputFile.WriteLine(line);
```

Alternatively, you could replace the whole loop with this:

```
File.WriteAllLines("that long path", values);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Justin : Please mark the answer that solved your problem as "accepted" by pressing the tick/check mark on the left of the post. But since both actually solve the problem, mark the one that you found was the most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code. Try this:

```
outputFile.WriteLine(line);
```